# Fetching Data in GridView Cells/Column

Tags: vb.net

I am a newbie in VB.net(programming). I need your advice regarding Gridview control.

I have a gridview loaded with two columns-one column(Name)is with some Text,another(Price) is empty.

I have got a TextBox with the data of Name and Price.

Now,I would like to loop through the Textbox,and see if the Data/symbols of the Column(Name) of GridView Control matches with the Data in Textbox.

If the Names of the GridView’s First Column’s data matches with the names of the Textbox,then the Price data should be fetched in the Second Column(Price) of GridView.

To make it more clear,say :

I have the following data in Textbox :

Name- Price

AB- 50

DE- 80

And I have two columns in GridView with following setups :

Name(column1) – Price(column2)

AB- Empty
DE- Empty

Now,how can I get the Price Data of Textbox,and fetch them into the Column2 of Gridview matching the Names of Column1. So,the output in GridView should be :

Name(column1) – Price(column2)

AB- 50
DE- 80

So far,I have been able to just loop through the first column of GridView…..I’m not sure how to get the data from Textbox and fetch the data into Column2 of GridView.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

> Public Class Form1
>
> ```
> Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
>
>     'Data of GridView
>     Dim dt As New DataTable()
>     dt.Columns.Add("Name")
>     dt.Columns.Add("Price")
>     dt.Rows.Add(New [Object]() {"AB"})
>     dt.Rows.Add(New [Object]() {"DE"})
>     Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
>
>
>     'Data of Textbox
>     TextBox1.Text = "AB, 50" & vbNewLine & "DE, 100"
>
>
> End Sub
>
>
>
>
> Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>     'loop through the gridview
>     Dim marketvalue As String
>     For Each r As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
>         marketvalue = r.Cells(0).Value
>         MessageBox.Show(marketvalue)
>     Next
> End Sub End Class
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a separate function to get the price from your TextBox

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'loop through the gridview
    Dim marketvalue As String
    Dim price As String
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows

        marketvalue = r.Cells(0).Value
        MessageBox.Show(marketvalue)

        'Get the price by calling a function and update it back to the DataGrid
        price = get_price(marketvalue)
        r.Cell(1).Value = price
    Next
End Sub
```

The following function can return you the price by passing the name parameter, otherwise empty if the name is not found

```
Private Function get_price(ByVal strName As String) As String

    Dim string_array() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(System.Environment.vbNewLine)
    For Each s As String In string_array
        Dim string_detail() As String = s.Split(",")
        If string_detail(0) = strName Then
            Return Trim(string_detail(1))
        End If
    Next

    Return ""
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for your feedback. I just solved my problem with your help. You are a life saver,my friend. My problem is solved!!!! Thanks a lot for your help.